# Virtualmin 'Feed to Program' can't open file

Tags: php, postfix-mta, webmin

I'm running Virtualmin on a Centos6 vps server with several domains. I'm trying to send email to an email alias which forwards to a php script.

The email is returned undeliverable with the following message...

```
Command died with status 1: "php
/home/mydomain/public_html/mail_pipe.php". Command output: Could not
open input file: /home/mydomain/public_html/mail_pipe.php
```

I have the path defined as

```
php /home/mydomain/public_html/mail_pipe.php
```

I've set file permissions to 0777+x

Inside mail_pipe.php I have a mail parsing script I have used before. Since that didn't work, right now I'm just trying to do something so I can see if the file was accessed, since the error msg says that it could not open the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    $myFile = "steve.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');

    $stringData = "File was opened \n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

I'm pretty sure it's actually trying to open the right file, since I get a file not found error when the target file is not there.

I had help the last time I did this. He did all the server side set up, while I handled the php script. So I'm a little out of my element here.

Comment: You don't need "php" at the front of this, since the program will have a shell that can read the shebang and act appropriately. I'm able to reproduce the problem, even without that, and will track down what's going on. It should actually work as-is, I think. (And you don't need 777. It just needs to be executable. The script would run as the owner. But, I suspect we have a bug in the code where it drops privileges. I'm talking to Jamie about it.)

Comment: I've opened a ticket about it here: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/36469

Comment: Whatever your problem is, **chmod 0777 is wrong and dangerous**.  You should back out this change and reset the permissions to something sane.  Currently, anybody with access to the box can change your script to do anything they like. (Even if you think you are alone on the box, you should not be surprised if you aren't, especially with this lack of attention to basic security.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after talking to Jamie about this, there's only a very limited use case for this particular workflow that works.

But, there is a way to achieve what you're after, which is to create a user for this action, and then login to Usermin as that user and setup the forwarding to your script as that user.

The reason it doesn't work in Virtualmin is that the aliases are being processed as the nobody (or whatever the postfix user on your system is) user, which has no access to user home directories. When creating it under Usermin, it will execute the action via procmail as the user that created the rule, and so the user will have the permissions needed to run the script and write to the file.

An alternative workaround, if the script doesn't need to write anything to the user's home (such as a complex auto-responder or something) would be to put your script in a location that nobody has access to.

We're currently discussing whether to remove this from the Virtualmin form (since it has such limited use and can be confusing), or to make it actually work as expected. I lean toward making it work as expected, but doing it securely given the current way things work might be challenging.

Comment: Awesome. On account of this information, I was able to get it working. Thanks so much. Here shortly, I'll add another answer with some detail on how I got this working.

Comment: swelljoe... trying to set up piping on a new server, but the option to feed to program is no longer there. Where did you move it?

Comment: It should still be there in the Usermin form for any user (i.e. login to Usermin as the user whose mailbox you want to redirect to a script). I suspect Jamie removed the option in Virtualmin because of the reasons I mentioned above. If you have trouble finding the option in Usermin let me know.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I used to get this working using Virtualmin 4.14.

From Virtualmin home, select the desired domain.

Click "Edit Users"

Create/select the user which will forward.

Click "Login to Usermin" at the bottom. (note: if it's not there, restart Usermin)

Click "Usermin" in upper left corner next to Virtualmin logo. (not intuitive)

Click "Mail" to open the mail menu.

Click "Mail Forwarding and Replies"

Click "Add a mail forwarding rule"

Click "Enable"

Select "Feed to program"

Enter full path to your mail script. ie '/home/mydomain/public_html/mail_pipe.php'

File must: exist/ begin with shebang/ be executable

Many thanks Stuporglue for this script I used as my starting point...

https://github.com/stuporglue/mailreader

Comment: Hey Steve, sorry for digging up this old thread but I've run into the same problem. In your steps I don't have "mail Forwarding and Replies" under the Mail options anymore. I do have "Filter and Forward Mail" but I didn't find any Feed to Program option in there. Can you update this post?

Comment: @VeeK, Since I don’t use Virtualmun any longer, I have no way to verify any changes.  The instructions do specify a version of Virtualmin.  If you’re on a different version, I’m not sure I can offer any suggestions. Sorry. I would contact Virtualmin support.